# Integrating jhipster with ngx-admin

Tags: jhipster, ngx-admin

I am integrating ngx-admin(3.0.0) with jhipster. It's not loading the dashboard and showing spinner only.

I followed https://github.com/fstepho/dashboard to do the upgrade.

Committed my code to https://github.com/chaitut715/dashboard

There are no error messages.